# HSQLDB in-memory mode persistence with JBoss

Tags: jboss, hsqldb

Is it possible to use HSQLDB in in-memory mode and to save the data while JBoss is running and/or when JBoss stops?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An all-in-memory database has a URL in the form `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:thename`

With this type of database as with all other types, you can use `SCRIPT 'file path'` to save a copy of the database to the file you specify.

Now someone else can show you how to execute an SQL command in the JBoss process in different ways. I have seen some examples on the web in the past.